# Как сохранить объект JSON в Preferences и обратно?

Tags: android, json

Никак не могу найти материал, как сохранить объект JSON в Preferences и обратно.

Перевожу в строку->сохраню в префы->получаю строку... А как превратить обратно в JSON, не знаю. (

Натыкался на статьи, где юзалось Gson, но затмение ругается на этот тип, обновление импортов не помогает - обновления последние стоят.

Подскажите, или есть какой-то способ еще сохранить json, с базой работать не очень хочется - туда-сюда таскать данные, а так придется дописать немного строк и код почти не изменится.
Или, может, есть способ сохранить как-то объект типа `АrrayList<ArrayList<String[]>>`, не особо заморачиваясь?

Comment: > но затмение ругается

Ох. Не надо так.

Comment: что за объект JSON? как класс называется? JSONObject? Или вы имеете в виду класс, который вы сами создали, и заполнили из JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

туда

```
editor.putString("jsondata", jobj.toString());
```

обратно

```
String strJson = sharedPref.getString("jsondata","0"); 
if(!strJson.equals("0")) JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(strJson);
```

Comment: >> if(strJson != null)

всегда будет true, т. к. значение поумолчанию вы подставляете "0"

Comment: да, вы правы. Пофиксил )

Comment: Да,да))долго я тупил.и только через пять минут после того как задал вопрос вспомнил-что JSON по сути и есть строка)))